# Wrong type for attribute Expected found BigDecimal

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I'm not sure why it's failing on this particular field and I have couple of other fields with same inputField, what I'm doing wrong here?

> Wrong type for attribute `<c:invoicedetail InvoiceAmount="{!myinvoice.Invoice_Amount__c}">`. Expected  Invoice__c,
>   found BigDecimal  (Line: 1, Column: -1)

Here is my very simple VF component:

```
<apex:attribute name="InvoiceAmount" description="Invoice Amount" type="invoice__c" required="true"/>
<many other inputfields here....
<apex:inputField id="in" value="{!InvoiceAmount.Invoice_Amount__c}"/>
```

VF page:

```
<c:mycomponent  InvoiceAmount="{!myinvoice.Invoice_Amount__c}"
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class InvoiceController {
    public InvoiceController() {
       Invoice__c myinvoice = [/*SOQL*/];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the record instead of its field. Since you seem to reference other fields on the record, this is the route you should take to fix your issue. I would rename your attribute to `invoice` or `invoiceRecord` instead.

```
<c:mycomponent invoice="{!myInvoice}" />
```

Then your component would be:

```
<apex:attribute
    name="invoice"
    description="Invoice Record"
    type="Invoice__c"
    required="true"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!invoice.Invoice_Amount__c}" />
<apex:inputField value="{!invoice.AnotherField__c}" />
```

Comment: what is the best practice in this situation?

Comment: if i try to change to type="Decimal" in the VF component then I'm getting this error `<apex:inputField> can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable`

Comment: I do not think so, I have posted VF page, VF Comp, and Controller, why do you think I'm giving incomplete picture

Comment: @AbuHamzah You must use `type="Invoice__c"` because you have many `inputField` tags.

Comment: I have exactly how you have laid-out and when I have this in my VF page `<c:mycomponent invoice="{!myInvoice}" />` then getting this error `unknown property create apex property invoice.invoice__c` error

Comment: @AbuHamzah Is there a field on the `Invoice__c` object called `Invoice__c`?

Comment: i have field on the object `Invoice__c` called `Invoice_Amount__c`

Comment: So why do you have `invoice.invoice__c` anywhere in your markup?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36363/discussion-between-abu-hamzah-and-adrian-larson).